# XHR calls return empty

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to AJAX and I am trying to make a call to my json file but it is not returning anything in console. I looked into network tab, the xhr status is 200.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.readyState = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }
}
xhr.open('GET','data/task.json');
xhr.send();
```

and task.json is

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Clerk",
            "employer": {
                "name": "AOL"
            },
            "location": "Floria",
            "salary": "$45k+"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried parsing it and using console to print it out but the console is empty as well.

Comment: add `&& this.status == 200` to `(xmr.readyState ==4)` also use double `==` not `===`. Also you need `xhttp.onreadystatechange` not `xmr.readySate`

Comment: I'd suggest you read the XHR documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest to see where you went wrong - it should be obvious that xhr.readyState can't be a function **AND** a number - hint: onreadystatechange ... or, in 2018, `load` event

Comment: ^ Hint: It's do do with the xhr.method used.

Comment: absolutely nothing to do with xhr.method - because an instance XMLHttpRequest does not have a `.method` property :p

Comment: @ZombieChowder thanks. It was my mistake. New in js I guess

Comment: I'm adding an answer, throwing some light *why* exactly you need those.

Comment: Probably worded poorly, but I meant to imply that `xhr.readyState` should be `xhr.onreadystatechange`. What should I refer to this as?

Comment: @Lewis mistake we all make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things to notice in the request that you are making.

1. You need to add the `status` to `200` because it's the **OK** status. Meaning that your request go through. So that part will exactly become `(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)`.
2. You also need to change from using triple equal signs `===` to `==` because you are not comparing by **TYPE** as a triple equals is used in JS.
3. Using the event handler `xhttp.onreadystatechange` instead of `xmr.readySate`. Here is a [link to the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange).

So it should become:

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }
}
xhr.open('GET','data/task.json');
xhr.send();
```

Here is a detailed documentation from W3Schools [Documentation with example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You need `onreadystatechange` not `readyState`

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }
}
xhr.open('GET','data/task.json');
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xhr.readyState you should use xhr.onreadystatechange
like that:
xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){

```
if(xhr.readyState === 4){
    console.log(xhr.responseText)
}
```

}